# How does a MacOSX VPN connection route traffic by default?

Tags: mac, vpn, routing, cisco-vpn-client

I connect to a VPN from home to work.  I use Mac OSX 10.6.x's built-in Cisco support to connect.  There are no non-default settings after authentication (eg to do with routing).

How does network traffic get routed?  As in, if I browse to a site, does the browser try to reach the site via the VPN connection?

How can I configure things such that only some traffic uses the VPN - as in, there are only a few addresses and IPs that I would want to go to the VPN for; the rest I'd want to use my own internet connection for.

Answer (score 0):

You should config you vpn server's split net. So only the IPs in your split nets would route through vpn gateway.

Comment: Is that something that I can do as a client, with no admin-rights to the server-end?